# Flutter tabview refresh issue

Tags: tabs, dart, flutter, tabview

I have a TabBarView in my main.dart and every tab got a class to show the content(it's listview object), when i go between the tabs, the listview page refresh everytime, is it normal for tabbarview? I don't expect it will refresh everytime when i go between the tabs.

is it the problem my class? how to fix this? the code is something like this.

```
    class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final catID;

  ListWidget(this.catID);


  _ListWidgetState createState() => new _ListWidgetState(catID);
}

class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> {

  var catID;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchListData();
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return new Scaffold(.......
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understood you well, you are complaining about the refreshing because you need the views to save their states after moving between tabs. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13080) on the subject and there is a way around this problem mentioned in the comments.

**Update:**

There is a workaround for this issue by using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` which you can learn more about in this [article](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc).

Answer (score 30):

MahMoos is right, however it's good to have an example here ...

1. Use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
2. override wantKeepAlive property and return true

`

```
class ListWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ListWidgetState createState() => _ListWidgetState();

}

class _ListWidgetState extends State<ListWidget> with 
                  AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ListWidget>{ // ** here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context)
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; // ** and here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. But, when I use AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin, the widget's build method shows this error:
""This method overrides a method annotated as '@mustCallSuper' in 'AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin', but doesn't invoke the overridden method.""

Comment: Good catch, I have added super.build(context), thanks!

Comment: None of these solutions is working for me

Answer (score 4):

If you want that your Tab view data does not refresh when you change Tab you should use

> AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin

```
class BaseScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  BaseScreen(this.title, this.listener, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

}

class BaseScreenState extends State<BaseScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    primaryColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: getAppBar(),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

I was facing the same issue and [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc) helped me.

Happy Coding.